# Handling dependencies of an Eclipse plugin built with Tycho, using a Target Platform

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, target-platform

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin with Tycho, and I want to handle my dependencies using a target platform, following the steps described in this [tutorial](http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/tycho-build-8-using-target-platform.html). 
But when I try to compile my plugin project (using clean install) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.codeandme.tycho.plugin 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.codeandme.tycho.plugin 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Here is the pom.xml of my plugin project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>tycho_example</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.releng</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../com.codeandme.tycho.releng</relativePath>
    </parent>
</project>
```

and here is the pom.xml of the parent project (releng):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tycho_example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho.version>0.22.0</tycho.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>tycho_example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.releng.targetplatform</artifactId>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>../com.codeandme.tycho.plugin</module>

        <module>../com.codeandme.tycho.releng.targetplatform</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

and here is the pom.xml of my target platform:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.releng.targetplatform</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-target-definition</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>tycho_example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../com.codeandme.tycho.releng</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>tycho_example</groupId>
</project>
```

and finally the .tpd of the target platform:

```
target "Tycho Tutorial"

with source requirements

location "http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150519210750/repository/" mars-orbit {
    org.apache.commons.lang3
}

location "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars" mars-release {
    org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
    org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group
    org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group
    org.eclipse.ui.trace
    org.eclipse.pde.feature.group
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui` doesn't appear in your target definition, does it?

Comment: where should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

In your target definition you included `org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group`, while the original tutorial requested you to include `org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group`. That's why the UI bundle is missing.

You can easily check the actual content of the target platform: right click the `.tpd` file, choose "generate target definition", open the newly generated `.target` file, wait for Eclipse to resolve it (watch the progress view), and after it has been resolved, the "contents" page of the target editor shows the plugins available in that target platform.

Comment: I replaced `org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group` by  `org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group` but I still have the same error. I also checked the content of the target platform and the UI bundle is there!